# Access token validation failure when trying to get calendars from Office 365

Tags: php, api, outlook, calendar, office365

I'm currently working on a webservice which has its own calendar, and I'm trying to synchronizer this calendar with the clients Exchange calendars.
So far I've been doing tests with an outlook mail address (...@outlook.com) and it works great.

I use OAuth for authentication process, redirect the client to : https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize etc ... then retrieve access and refresh token, then I try to get the calendar of the client using GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars and sending the access token in the headers.

So far it worked perfectly with the @outlook.com mail address, but I've tried the same process with an Office 365 address (...@mybusiness.onmicrosoft.com) and it gives me a 401 Error :

error": {
    "code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken",
    "message": "Access token validation failure.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "48dbe66d-0b82-490b-a84a-8944eaffc8ea",
      "date": "2017-05-15T07:51:59"
    }

I used Postman to do the same work with same web address but using a token I received with the OAuth 2 authentication of Postman, and it worked. The access token I use in the webservice is valid so I have no idea why it would work in Postman.

Any idea why it doesn't work now ? My application is not registered on Azure Active Directory but on apps.dev.microsoft.com and it worked great until now.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, I had to adjust the size of the access token in the database. It used to be a VARCHAR(1500) which was enough for a token for @outlook.com but access token for office 365 account is longer, and when I registered it in the database it was cut off and I was sending just a piece of the access token.